# How to handle multiple errors in React?

Tags: reactjs, api, error-handling

In my React app I have created the below `NoteDetail` component. My question is: What is the best practice to handle multiple `error` variables, in this case one that I might get from my `GET` API-request and another from my `DELETE` API-request? The first solution that comes into my head is to have dedicated `getError` and `deleteError` variables, but I don't know if this is the recommended way to handle this.

```
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import useFetch from "./useFetch";
import { api } from "./api";
import axios from "axios";

const NoteDetail = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { data: note, error, loading } = useFetch(api.notes.retrieve(id));
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    axios
      .delete(api.notes.delete(id))
      .then((response) => {
        setLoading(false);
        history.pushState("/");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setError(error.message || error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="note-details">
      {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {error && <div>{error}</div>}
      {note && (
        <article>
          <h2>{note.title}</h2>
          <p>Written by {note.author}</p>
          <div>{note.body}</div>
          <Link to={"/update/" + note.id}>
            <button>Edit</button>
          </Link>
          <button onClick={handleClick}>Delete</button>
        </article>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default NoteDetail;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way, according to the doc, would be [`Error Boundaries`](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html#introducing-error-boundaries) concept.

> Error boundaries are React components that catch JavaScript errors
> anywhere in their child component tree, log those errors, and display
> a fallback UI instead of the component tree that crashed.

A class component becomes an error boundary if it defines a new lifecycle method called componentDidCatch(error, info):

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    // Display fallback UI
    this.setState({ hasError: true });
    // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
    logErrorToMyService(error, info);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
    }
    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

Then you can wrap your other components by this `ErrorBoundary` component as below:

```
<ErrorBoundary>
  <MyWidget />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Just remember that error boundaries only catch errors in the components below them in the tree.

[LIVE DEMO](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/wqvxGa?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

I am curious what happens when you have multiple error boundaries

```
function renderWithError() {
  throw new Error('error');
}

function A() {
  return <ErrorBoundary name="boundary-2">{renderWithError()}</ErrorBoundary>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary name="boundary-1">
      <A />
    </ErrorBoundary>
  )
}
```